# Show that $\frac{∂z}{∂x}+ \frac{∂z}{∂y}=(x+y-1)z$ if $z= \frac{e^{xy}}{e^x + e^y}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Show that $\frac{∂z}{∂x}+ \frac{∂z}{∂y}=(x+y-1)z$ if $z= \frac{e^{xy}}{e^x + e^y}$

What I've done so far:

$\frac{∂}{∂x}(\frac{e^{xy}}{e^x + e^y})= \frac{ye^{xy}(e^x+e^y)-e^{xy}e^x}{{(e^x + e^y)}^2}=\frac{e^{xy}y(e^x +e^y)-e^{xy+x}}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$

$\frac{∂}{∂y}(\frac{e^{xy}}{e^x + e^y})= \frac{xe^{xy}(e^x+e^y)-e^{xy}e^y}{{(e^x + e^y)}^2}=\frac{e^{xy}x(e^x +e^y)-e^{xy+y}}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$

I don't see how adding up these two fractions would be equal to $(x+y-1)z$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add them, you do get the result, though I have tried and shown a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \displaystyle z= \frac{e^{xy}}{e^x + e^y}$

So, $ \displaystyle  \ln z= xy - \ln{ (e^x + e^y)}$

Taking derivative wrt $x$ and $y$,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = y - \frac{e^x}{e^x+e^y}$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = x - \frac{e^y}{e^x+e^y}$

Adding both and simplifying gives the desired result.

Edit: your working also gives the result once you add them.

$ \displaystyle \frac{e^{xy}y(e^x +e^y)-e^{xy+x}}{(e^x+e^y)^2} + \frac{e^{xy}x(e^x +e^y)-e^{xy+y}}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$

$ \displaystyle = e^{xy} \bigg[\frac{y(e^x +e^y)-e^{x} + x (e^x +e^y) - e^{y}}{(e^x+e^y)^2} \bigg]$

$ \displaystyle = e^{xy} \bigg[\frac{x+y-1}{e^x+e^y} \bigg] = (x + y -1 ) \cdot z$

Comment: Thanks added as accepted answer!

Comment: You are welcome.